# Artemis Space Program

Tags: moonwalking, lunar-base, artemis-program

Is NASA going to initiate setting up a base with this programme. That would be really cool, as it would be useful for research, mining and space flights. Though, if not, where is the speculated first base of humans outside earth?

Comment: My understanding was that, on top of the other objectives, a moon base was part of the end goal of the program. I think the words were "return to the moon, and this time to stay" I may be paraphrasing though. I will have to look up a more official source though.